# What does media type print

Tags: html, css

I am new for css, still I'm trying to learn media types, i can't understand the usage of media type print, can anyone please explain what really does media type print

for an example what happen I use this css

```
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It causes the CSS to only apply when the document is rendered to a printer … for putting on paper.

[image: A printer]

Comment: Of course it does. Print Preview wouldn't be useful if it didn't show you what was going to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a webpage having black back color background then during printing It uses lot of ink. So, the thing I have to do is to change the background color to white and font color to black(if using white earlier).
This thing can be done by using

```
@media print
{
......
......//here write your code which you want during printing
}
```

this is an example for using @media print(But it have lot of other plus points also).
Yes, you can see the change during print preview